# casting LinkButton Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a LinkButton inside of a telerik grid when it is clicked it updates the database. The trouble comes at the first line where I recieve an error that I am unable to cast the radgrid to linkButton. Can someone shed a little light. Here is the Error Msg.

> Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton

Here is my method:

```
protected void rad_grdCompleteRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btnCompleteRequest = (LinkButton)sender;
    int requestID = Convert.ToInt32(btnCompleteRequest.Attributes["RequestID"]);
    SqlManager.UpdateRequest(requestID, 3);
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

Comment: then sender represents your grid (Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid) and cannot be converted to a LinkButton. What event is `rad_grdCompleteRequest`

Comment: It is the event to preform an update.

Comment: show the event you were trying to handle e.g in your markup - `OnRowUpdating?` or `myGrid.RowUpdating += new EventHandler(...)`. Show one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**.aspx**

// Normal Mode

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

// Edit Mode

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton LinkButton1 = sender as LinkButton;
    // Do your logic here
}
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns.